# Setting ScrollViewInsets makes scrollbar start from top

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code to set my scrollView's inset:

```
// top margin for table
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
CGFloat navbarHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
CGFloat statusHeight = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
CGFloat tabBarHeight = self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;
CGFloat filterBtnsContainerHeight = 36.0;
CGFloat insetTopMargin = navbarHeight + statusHeight + filterBtnsContainerHeight;
[self.postsTable setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(insetTopMargin,0,tabBarHeight,0)];
```

It works great, except that the scrollbar now starts from top and ends at bottom. It should start after the navigaton bar and end before the tabbar. Is there a way to set the container for the scrollbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting your `scrollViewInset` try `tableView.scrollIndicatorInset = tableView.scrollViewInset`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve this issue in storyboard. Select your view Controller and then go attribute inspector then select under top bars. It's because your view is set at 0 whereas it should be at 64 as you've added navigation bar. Just uncheck **under top bars** and you should good to go.

Hope this helps.